Can we show that $\frac{n^x}{n+\ln(n)}$ is decreasing for $n\ge n_0 \ge 1$ and $0 \le x <1$ without using derivatives?
I'm studying the behavior of this sequence
\begin{equation}
a_n = \frac{n^x}{n+\ln(n)}
\end{equation}
and I want to prove that exists $n_0 \ge 1$ such that for $n\ge n_0 \ge 1$ and $0 \le x <1$ $a_n$ is decreasing.
By defining the function
\begin{equation}
f(t) = \frac{t^x}{t+\ln(t)}\quad \text{with} \quad t\ge1 
\end{equation}
I have that
\begin{equation}
f'(t) = \frac{t^{-1 + x} \left[-1 + t (-1 + x) + x \ln(t)\right]}{[t + \ln(t)]^2} \le0
\end{equation}
if and only if
\begin{equation}
g(t) = -1 + t (-1 + x) + x \ln(t) \le 0.
\end{equation}
Now I have that
\begin{equation}
g'(t) = \frac{t(x-1) + x}{t} \ge 0 \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad t(x-1) + x \ge 0  \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad t \le \frac{x}{1-x}.
\end{equation}
Therefore, $g(t)$ has a maximum in $t=\max\left(1,\frac{x}{1-x}\right)$ and after that it decreases definitely.
From this, and from the fact that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{t\to\infty} g(t) = \lim_{t\to\infty} -1 + t (-1 + x) + x \ln(t) = -\infty
\end{equation}
I conclude that exist $t_0$ such that $g(t_0)\le 0$ and $g(t)\le g(t_0) \le 0 \ \ \forall\, t\ge t_0$.
Therefore, $f'(t)\le 0 \ \ \forall\, t\ge t_0$ which implies that $f(t)$ is decreasing for $t\ge t_0$
Finally, for $n\ge n_0\ge t_0$ we have the thesis.
There is an easiest way to prove this? Can it be done without using derivatives?

It's intuitive that $a_n$ will be decreasing after some point, since $\ln(n)$ is eventually dominated by both $n$ and $n^x$. Disregarding the $\ln(n)$, we would have that $\frac{n^x}{n}$ is decreasing. That should be the main idea of a proof without using derivaties.
